# How can i see what's in garbage collector

Tags: python

I am learning security challenge. One of this challenge ask me to retrieve data which has been destroyed and is kept in memory until garbage collector fires.

I have tried a lot of things. I want to know if it is possible to dump process memory from python console.

Also, the challenge gives us a python console, but there is a stopwatch instead of ">>>". How can they do something like that ?
I just have an ssh access which launch python console.

Thanks

Comment: `import gc; gc.get_objects()`

Comment: sys.ps1 / sys.ps2 controls the prompt in the standard Python REPL: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.ps1

Comment: Thanks. I have ever tried but import is forbidden

Comment: In Python3.3+ you can circumvent the ban on import by using `__loader__.load_module('gc').get_objects()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to see whats in garbage.

```
import gc

def dump_garbage():
    """
    show us what's the garbage about
    """
    # force collection
    print("\nGARBAGE:")
    gc.collect()

    print("\nGARBAGE OBJECTS:")
    for x in gc.garbage:
        s = str(x)
        if len(s) > 80: s = s[:80]
        print(type(x),"\n  ", s)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import gc
    gc.enable()
    gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

    # make a leak
    l = []
    l.append(l)
    del l

    # show the dirt ;-)
    dump_garbage()
```

Comment: I do not understand: If you collect() before printing content, there will be nothing in the gc ?

Comment: @Bob5421 yes it seems so.